# sbt compilation error: no augmentString method in StringOps

Tags: java, scala, submit, sbt

I'm on Fedora 21 with:

- scala 2.10.3
- java 1.8.0
- sbt 0.13.1

`Scala` and `java` are installed using `yum`. `Sbt` is installed manually and to the end of `~/.bashrc` file the line `export PATH=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/sbt/bin:$PATH` is added to make sbt available in the terminal. Then when I cd to the `/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/example` and run `sbt -h`, the help message is normally displayed but if start sbt:

```
[igor@prague example]$ sbt
Loading /home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
OpenJDK Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
    at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<init>(ConsoleLogger.scala:129)
    at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<clinit>(ConsoleLogger.scala)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.<init>(Main.scala:52)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.<clinit>(Main.scala)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
```

If I download `scala 2.10.4` and `yum remove scala` and add the new scala to the path like I did it manually with sbt, the same error remains.

Is it possible to make sbt working? I need to run sbt submit command in order to submit my assignments to the Coursera.

Comment: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString" most of the times this error occurs due to dependency jar version mismatch.Make sure you have correct version of the jar in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but it may be an issue with java 8.
From typesafe [blog](https://typesafe.com/blog/scala-211-has-arrived) for scala 2.11

`The Scala 2.11 series targets Java 6, with (evolving) experimental support for Java 8. In 2.11, Java 8 support is mostly limited to reading Java 8 bytecode and parsing Java 8 source. We will be expanding Scala's (experimental) Java 8 support and interop throughout the 2.11 series.`

If 2.11 version has only experimental support, then 2.10 will also not have a proper support for Java 8. You can do the course on java 7. It's an awesome course BTW :)

Comment: I added these lines to the `.bashrc` file:
`export PATH=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/sbt/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/jdk1.7.0_72/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/jdk1.7.0_72
export JRE_HOME=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/jdk1.7.0_72/jre
export PATH=/home/igor/Documents/Projects/Scala/Assignments/scala-2.10.4/bin:$PATH`.
This way java 1.8 is ignored and java 1.7 is used by sbt.